# How to extract the value of literal phantom type?

Tags: haskell

I use a type lateral phantom type (status) to change the type of a record field (via type family). How can I get the value back?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}

data Status = Valid | Invalid deriving(Show)

data A s = A (TF s)

type family TF (s:: Status) where
    TF Valid = Int
    TF Invalid = Either String Int

status :: A s -> Status
status = ???
```

How can I write status?

### Update

To clarify, `s` is a value of type Status. Therefore, I expect `status (A 3 :: A Valid)` (for example) to be `Valid`.

### Update2

I found a solution with typeclass (see my own answer), however I would much prefer a way to demote a type to its value.

Comment: How do you ensure that the value stored is the same that the value used by TF ?

Comment: right - I missed that data-kind part (sorry) - this way `A s -> s` will be a problem anyway

Comment: What should `status (A 3 :: A Valid)` be? A value of type `Valid`? But `Valid` is not a type (hasn't kind `*`). I don't think this is doable: `(->)` requires two types, and `s` is not a type. I would expect this to trigger a kind error on `A s -> s`.

Comment: @chi, you could make a singleton GADT. `data Ay s where Validy :: Ay Valid; Invalidy :: Ay Invalid` then return a singleton instead.

Comment: @chi the answer should be `Valid` (question updated).

Comment: mb14, I think it would be helpful if you gave more background about what you're trying to accomplish, ultimately.

Comment: Also, the *type* `Status` is largely disconnected from the *kind* `Status`, because Haskell is not (yet?) a fully dependently typed language.

Comment: @dfeur This is not a XY problem. I am curious to see the answer to this question. The background (not sure it helps) is to display a html form and have one type to represent all the different "shape" corresponding to the steps of validation, or parse a csv where different line can represent different type (but all have the same columns). You can see more [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4db04s/how_to_modelize_datatype_to_handle_error_and/)

Comment: If `s = Valid`, we do not have `status (A 3 :: A s) = Valid :: s = Valid`. I guess you want `status :: A s -> Status` instead?

Comment: @chi: You are right. question updated.

Comment: There is no way, in Glasgow Haskell, to demote a type to its associated value. That's what I meant when I said the `Status` type and kind are pretty much disconnected. The `singletons` package offers Template Haskell bits to create types, promotions, and demotions in one go, but GHC proper won't prove them correct.

Comment: It seems we can demote nat and symbol, maybe I can use that ?

Comment: @mb14 If you want some general function to convert a type to the value from which it is promoted, this is simply impossible. As mentioned by another commenter, packages like `singletons` accomplish this by generating a bunch of boilerplate for each type with TH. The only reason it works with `Nat` and `Symbol` is because they are special, built-in kinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type class work but you need to roll down all the cases

```
class HasStatus where
  status :: s -> status

instance HasStatus (A Valid) where
  status = const Valid
instance HasStatus (A Invalid) where
  status = const Invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write your function `status :: A s -> Status` simply because (in GHC) functions do not receive any kind of representation of their type arguments at runtime, and without knowing anything about `s`, you have no useful information in the argument of type `A s`. This applies regardless of whether `s` has a kind promoted from a data type or a traditional kind like `*`.

In order to get out information that varies at runtime (your `Status` result) you must provide some input that varies at runtime. This can be either a type class context, as you found, or you could add the information to `A` itself:

```
data A (s :: Status) where
    A1 :: Int -> A Valid
    A2 :: Either String Int -> A Invalid
```

and then you can implement `status` by pattern-matching on the argument.

Comment: Everything is known at compile time and the typeclass solution works so it's possible.

Comment: It's not true that everything is known at compile time, for example if you put an `A s` in some kind of existential data structure that forgets `s`, and then take it back out. A function of type `A s -> Status` is not the same as a function of type `(HasStatus s) => A s -> Status`, even if there are instances for both "values" of `HasStatus`. The type class solution does work exactly when the type `s` actually is known.